# Box2D implementation issue

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics-engine

I am trying to put Box2D into my app. I have the Box2D folder from the latest Cocos2D release. I drag it into my project and I add it to the destination group folder and I get 4 errors, it is where the compiler can't find b2Collision.h, b2BroadPhase.h, and b2Collision.h, I know there are 2 errors for the collision. There is another error but it comes and goes based upon how to implement it.
Anyway, with the way I am implementing it, how do I get rid of these errors? Does anyone have any ideas/tips?

Thanks!!!

Comment: make sure your makefile/solution whatever has an include path setting that points to where the Box2D include files are.

Comment: I am confused, what do you mean? I am new to Box2D, how are you saying I should fix this?

Comment: @MyApps I suggest to check [Implementing Box2d](http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls) It is really sufficiently perfect tutorial.

Comment: You could also just install Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com) where it works out of the box. Preview 5 to be released in the next 48 hours uses the latest Box2D v2.2.1, and you'll get an example project plus a working Pinball game made with Box2D.

Comment: @MyApps if your compile is complaining it can't find certain include files, it is not a Box2D problem, it is a build environment problem. Compilers typically have a default set of directories that are searched for include files. if you install a library that has include files in directories not in the default path, you have to add the path to the compiler invocation. what is your development environment?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D What is the difference between Kobold2D and Box2D? Does Kobold have the same functionality that Box2D has?

Comment: No, Kobold2D is an improved Cocos2D, and includes several ready-to-use projects with working Box2D integration, ie a Pinball game.

Comment: Oh ok so Box2D is in Kobold2D? So for example, would I be able to use Box2D's gravity feature or collision detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"${SRCROOT}/path_to_box2d_folder"` to your `User Header Search Path` and set `Always Search User Paths` to `yes` in your project build settings.